# Drawing box plot with gnuplot 4.6

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

In the [official document](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf)  in page 44 it says, to draw a boxplot

```
# Place a boxplot at x coordinate 1.0 representing the y values in column 5
plot 'data' using (1.0):5
```

I cannot get it work, when I do above gnuplot only draws  points, not a box. Anybody knows how to do it? In the guide, the example shows a box plot (page 44 the   figure on the right)

I am using gnuplot 4.6 patch level 4. I am not getting any errors, but the box is just not there.

When I use the demo script

```
plot 'silver.dat' using (1):2, '' using (2):(5*$3)
```

it works, what does the second part after the comma mean? **(  '' using (2):(5*$3) )**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was specifying box widths, but finally found that this should be added at least

```
set style data boxplot
```

optionally, you can add

```
set style fill solid 0.25 border -1
set style boxplot outliers pointtype 7
```